# excel - checking if dates over next n rows lie in a timespan

Tags: excel

I need to compute the following variable SIM:

```
SIM = d/130, in which d is the number of days in the next 130 business days that lie between the second business day in May and the 15th business day of October.
```

My computation of it (in excel) currently looks like this (which is not correct):

```
                 SIM
date                
1990-06-08  0.715385
1990-06-11  0.707692
1990-06-12  0.700000
1990-06-13  0.692308
1990-06-14  0.684615
1990-06-15  0.676923
1990-06-18  0.669231
1990-06-19  0.661538
1990-06-20  0.653846
1990-06-21  0.646154
1990-06-22  0.638462
1990-06-25  0.630769
1990-06-26  0.623077
1990-06-27  0.615385
1990-06-28  0.607692
1990-06-29  0.600000
1990-07-02  0.592308
1990-07-03  0.584615
1990-07-05  0.576923
1990-07-06  0.569231
1990-07-09  0.561538
1990-07-10  0.553846
1990-07-11  0.546154
1990-07-12  0.538462
1990-07-13  0.530769
1990-07-16  0.523077
1990-07-17  0.515385
1990-07-18  0.507692
1990-07-19  0.500000
1990-07-20  0.492308
...              ...
2015-03-23  1.000000
2015-03-24  1.000000
2015-03-25  1.000000
2015-03-26  1.000000
2015-03-27  1.000000
2015-03-30  1.000000
2015-03-31  1.000000
2015-04-01  1.000000
2015-04-02  1.000000
2015-04-06  1.000000
2015-04-07  1.000000
2015-04-08  1.000000
2015-04-09  1.000000
2015-04-10  1.000000
2015-04-13  1.000000
2015-04-14  1.000000
2015-04-15  1.000000
2015-04-16  1.000000
2015-04-17  1.000000
2015-04-20  0.992308
2015-04-21  0.984615
2015-04-22  0.976923
2015-04-23  0.969231
2015-04-24  0.961538
2015-04-27  0.953846
2015-04-28  0.946154
2015-04-29  0.938462
2015-04-30  0.930769
2015-05-01  0.923077
2015-05-04  0.915385
```

In Excel, is there an easy way to look over the next 130 rows (of dates) and see how many of them lie between a specific date range?

Comment: By "business days" you mean just week days? Because if you need to take holidays into account it gets more complicated.

Comment: Look into [bdate_range](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html), it should help you out a lot

Comment: I don't think that's too helpful because I already have all the business days, by index column has all the days I need. I'm just uncertain as to iterate over these dates and see how many of the next 130 days lie within 2nd BD of May and 15th BD of October @sacul

Comment: @jdehesa business days do not include holidays, but luckily currently my index already has the days I want. The tricky part for me is computing the range of 2nd business day of May to 15th business day of October

Comment: Would the result be (year, SIM) where SIM is the number of days in that year between the two dates divided by 130?

Comment: SIM is a daily variable, so for every day you look at the next 130 days  that lie between the two specified dates, and divide that by 130

Answer (score 1):

Assume you're in line 10 and the dates are col A, the following formula determines how many rows w/in the next 130 are within 150 days (inclusive)

```
=COUNTIF(A11:A140;"<="&A10+150)
```

As you don't want to go back a fixed amount of days - but back to May 2nd (if may 1st is a Sunday) or May 1st of a respective year, you could get the cutoff date (assuming again row 10) via

```
=IF(WEEKDAY(DATE(YEAR(A10);5;1))=1;DATE(YEAR(A10);5;2);DATE(YEAR(A10);5;1))
```

Bringing this all together would yield a slightly monstrous but (at least for me) working formula of

```
=COUNTIF(A11:A140;"<="&IF(WEEKDAY(DATE(YEAR(A10);5;1))=1;DATE(YEAR(A10);5;2);DATE(YEAR(A10);5;1)))
```

What it does is: it checks how many dates from Line 11 (one below current) until 140 (i.e. in the next 130 lines) is equal to or before May1/May2 of the year in line 10.

Here's more info on the COUNTIF thing: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/countif-function-e0de10c6-f885-4e71-abb4-1f464816df34

Comment: My dates are already in business days, so luckily I don't need to worry about that. I'm confused about the "within 150 days" part, I need to see specifically if it is between the 2nd BD of May and the 15th of October, which I think I'm just going to have as 5/2 and 10/15th. How can I reference this timespan? I'd make another column by hand but the issue is the years wouldn't match up.

Comment: 150 days was just an arbitrary example. Sry for overlooking this aspect of the question. to reference may 1st (or 2nd) of this year, you could try ```=IF(WEEKDAY(VALUE(CONCAT("01.05.";YEAR(TODAY()))))=1;VALUE(CONCAT("02.05.";YEAR(TODAY())));VALUE(CONCAT("01.05.";YEAR(TODAY()))))``` (or you could use ```YEAR(A88)``` to get the year of bespoke cell)

Comment: Seems to give me an error on `"01.05."`, is this supposed to be May 1st?

Comment: Could be that it depends on your locale. Let me try to get a better alternative (like ```=DATE```) and consolidate all above

Comment: all right, I updated the above answer; hope this is what you've been looking for...

Comment: I understand the formula, but it's giving me an error on my first countif range(A11:A140), and highlights A140?

Comment: Maybe you have a non-english Excel. Otherwise I don't know; sorry!

Comment: It seems like you use `;` instead of `,` for delimitations. I adjusted that, but seem to get a value of zero for row 10, and every row beneath. Is there an error in the formula?

Comment: ```;``` instead of ```,``` is indeed a locale question. Anyways, I'm running out of ideas what could be wrong at your end. Sry to let you down here; maybe s/o else will chime in with an idea...